# Invoking child controller methods from parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS application which has a screen like below. `Parent Controller` is associated with Main View that loads the initial template which has nested child views - `view1`, `view2` & `view3`. At any given time, only one of child views will be active. Each view has a form with some input elements which can be modified and saved with save button at the bottom. We have navigation links on left hand side. Clicking any of those links will switch the view based on the selection. These click-to-navigate handlers are configured in Parent controllers.

Now the problem I'm trying to solve is to **detect unsaved changes before navigating to a different view**. I already have means to detect state changes in a particular form. I'm looking for a way to invoke functions for doing state change check on child controllers from the click handlers in parent controller.

I think I can do this in one of the 2 ways

1. Get a reference to scope bound to my child views using `angular.element()` and invoke my function of interest on scope.
2. In all child controllers, `add a watcher on a property defined on parent controller's scope` which can be updated in click handlers based on selection.

But I'm not entirely convinced with these approaches and looking for a better way to achieve this.

Thanks for your time. Appreciate any help on this :)

[image]